# Record is being added to the DB with delay

Tags: php, jquery, sql, cakephp

I'm using Cakephp (on development mode) and my datasource is database/Mysql.

In my system I have the following process:

1. Visitor select 6 items
2. Visitor clicks on a button
3. On button's click I use jquery $.post to send the data to a php function that takes that data and add it to the database.
4. After that (or maybe not as it seems), they visitor is being redirected to the "payment page".

**This is the jquery script which is responsible to send the data to the php function "handle".**

```
$('.next-step').on('click', function(){

    var paymentPage = $(this).attr('data-href');

    var slotsData = [];
    var i = 0;
    $('.slot').each(function(){
        slotsData[i] = {
            'img-id': $(this).attr('data-id'),
            'img-src': $(this).attr('data-src'),
            'img-high-src': $(this).attr('data-high-src'),
            'img-page': $(this).attr('data-page')
            };
        i++;    
    }); 

    var setid = 0;

    $.post('/sets/handle', {k:'',setid:setid,setData:slotsData}, function(data){
                window.location = paymentPage;
    });

    return true;
});
```

**This is the php function handle**

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->request->onlyAllow('ajax');

    $set_id = (int)$this->request->data('setid');
    $images = serialize($this->request->data('setData'));


    //Key
    $cookie_key = $this->Cookie->read('visitor_key');
    if(isset($cookie_key) && $cookie_key != null)
    {
        $key = $cookie_key;
    }
    else
    {
        $key = $this->newKey();
        $this->Cookie->write('visitor_key', $key);
    }


    //Edit Mode
    if(isset($set_id) && $set_id > 0)
    {
        /*Some other irrelevant code */         
    }
    else //Creating a new set
    {
        $this->Set->create();
        $this->Set->save(array(
            'images' => $images,
            'visitor_key' => $key,
            'quantity' => 1
        ));

        AppController::logActivity( array('visitor_key' => $key, 'instagram_id' => 0, 'instagram_username' => ''), 'Created New Set', $this->Set->id );

        return json_encode(array('status' => 'created','setid' => $this->Set->id,'visitor_key'=>$key));
    }


}
```

**This is the php function Payment**

```
public function payment() {

    $this->set('title_for_layout', 'Review Your Order');
    /*
    debug( date("d-m-y H:i:s") );
    */                  
    $sets = $this->Set->findAllByVisitorKeyAndOrderId($this->Cookie->read('visitor_key'),'0');
    /*
    debug($sets);
    */      
    $onesetcost = Configure::read('Ecom.setcost');
    $visitor_key = $this->Cookie->read('visitor_key');

    $total_sets = 0;
    foreach($sets as $set){
        $total_sets += $set['Set']['quantity'];
    }
    $shippmentCost = $this->shippmentCostByQuantity($total_sets);           

    $this->set(compact('sets','onesetcost','visitor_key','shippmentCost'));

}
```

So the problem is the after getting to the Payment page, the "sets" variable doesn't contains the new data that recently has been added.

In order to find the problem I compared the creation time of the record (I have a "created" field in the sets table) to the time of which the payment page got loaded. (See commented commands).

It seems that the records is being added around 30 seconds after the payment page is being showed.
How is that possible?

I mean, the redirection is being processed after the record has being added to the DB.
I thought it's Cache, but i'm still using the default File Engine cache which seems not to cache records but only db scheme.

I've been looking for any related issue but ended with nothing,
I debugged and tried almost any idea I had but still I didn't find the source of the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `window.location = paymentPage;` code inside a success handler.

eg:

```
$.post('/sets/handle', {k:'',setid:setid,setData:slotsData}, function(data){
    // Do nothing in here
}).done(function( msg ) {
    window.location = paymentPage;
});
```

What's happening is that the user is being redirected to the new page at the same time as the request is happening.  If you wait until the request has been completed, then you should be OK.

More info on jquery ajax requests here: 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I was sure that `.done` and `.success` are basically the same. I'll try it and update you. Thanks.